# Make broken loop run again?

Tags: python, winapi

I made a program which prints 'F pressed!' when i press the button 'F'. I don't want it to spam my console with that so I made the While-Loop break after that. How can I make the function run again and make the program not stop working? Or just make the text only appear once everytime I press the button?

```
import win32api

while True:
    keystate = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x46)

    if keystate < 0:
        print('F pressed!')
        break
    else:
        pass
```

Thanks

Comment: take a `bool` variable outside loop.Make it true inside loop when priniting for first time

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how I could do that? I'm not that expirienced in Python and it would help me alot.

Answer (score 1):

**How can I make the function run again and make the program not stop working?**

The `break` statement terminates the loop containing it. Control of the program flows to the statement immediately after the body of the loop.

Therefore, you just remove `break` and everything is ok.

**Or just make the text only appear once everytime I press the button?**

> If the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the
>   previous call to [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate#return-value).

Try the code sample below:

```
import win32api

while True:
    keystate = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x46)&0x0001
    if keystate > 0:
       print('F pressed!')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: @user13591244 Glad to help you :)